# Как правильно установить кодировку?

Tags: java

подскажите как решить проблему, при компиляции кода на консоль в некоторых местах выводит знаки вопроса. Кодировку менял на UTF-8, менял jdk на более старую версию(помогло, но не во всех случаях).

```
public class MainDemo {
public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {
        Tovar [] tovars = {
                new Pants(Sizes.M, "40", "Black"),
                new Pants(Sizes.S, "40", "Yellow"),
                new Shirt(Sizes.M, "55", "White"),
                new Shirt(Sizes.XL, "55", "Black"),
                new Tie("58","Rose"),
                new Tie("60", "Black"),
                new Watch("70","White"),
                new Watch("120","Grey")
        };

        DressMarket dressMarket = new DressMarket();
        dressMarket.dressFemale(tovars);
        dressMarket.dressFemale(tovars);



public interface MaleClothes {
default void dressMale(){
    System.out.println("Одеваем мужчину");
}
```

}

```
public class Shirt extends Tovar implements FemaleClothes, MaleClothes{
public Shirt(Sizes size, String price, String color) {
    super(size, price, color);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Рубашка{" +
            "размер = " + getSize() +
            ", цена = " + getPrice() + " $" +
            ", цвет = " + getColor() +
            "}";
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин настроек

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: довольно очевидно, что в одном файле буквы кириллицы записаны у вас в одной кодировке, а в другом файле — в другоей.

Comment: где в исходном коде строка, которая выводится в виде вопросов? это не "`одеваем мужчину`" - не сходится по количеству символов и нет двоеточия. покажите код с данной строкой и покажите в какой кодировке данный файл(правый нижний угол в редакторе с открытым  текущим файлом)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

попробуй измени `Project Encoding` на default
для пропертей (Properties Files) наверно необязательно, но тоже попробуй

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас отображает символы. Не подскажите , есть ли возможность убрать скобки фигурные"{" при выводе на консоль метода toString?

Comment: да... в методе просто удали эти символы...только зачем? привыкай, это стандарт вывод для json