# проблемы при работе с кирилицей в spring boot 2.7.2

Tags: java, spring, кодировка, boot

Не пойму в чем дело - в intellije idea запускаю проект на spring boot 2 до версии 2.6.9 все работает нормально. На версиях 2.7.0 - 2.7.3 кириллица отображается ??????????????? знаками вопросов. Везде где можно кодировка указана utf-8. Шаблоны mustache в utf-8.

Comment: попробуй так [ссылка на ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450444/Как-правильно-установить-кодировку/1450462?noredirect=1#comment2590799_1450462)

Comment: нет, не помогает. и самое печальное что и после сборки в jar файл и запуска - те же самые крякозябры вместо кириллицы. При этом проблема имеет место на двух разных машинах, на одной убунту на второй винда, так, что дело видимо именно в spring boot, странно, что как будто у меня одного.

Comment: есть возможность взглянуть на код?